# aSmack,Sending a List<String> for Search using UserSearchManager returns IllegalStateException

Tags: android, asmack

i Am Trying to Send a List of Emails for search To the Server :

```
   List<String> mails = new ArrayList<String>();
   mails.add("myMail");
   UserSearchManager usm = new UserSearchManager(connection);
      Form searchForm = usm.getSearchForm("search.reza-hp");
      Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();
      answerForm.setAnswer("Email", true);
      answerForm.setAnswer("search",phoneContacts);
      ReportedData data = usm.getSearchResults(answerForm, "search.reza-hp");
```

But i get This Exception > IllegalArgumentException : This field only accept list of values

any Idea how should i prepare the List to Send?

LogCat:

```
  09-06 12:47:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(9769): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This 
field only accept list of values.
09-06 12:47:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(9769):     at 
org.jivesoftware.smackx.xdata.Form.setAnswer(Form.java:314)
09-06 12:47:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(9769):     at     
com.lifemate.lmmessenger.listviewengine.ListViewActivity.
getPhoneContacts(ListViewActivity.    java:879)
09-06 12:47:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(9769):     at  
com.lifemate.lmmessenger.listviewengine.ListViewActivity.
onViewCreated(ListViewActivity.jav
a:209)
09-06 12:47:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(9769):     at 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:956)
09-06 12:47:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(9769):     at 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
09-06 12:47:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(9769):     at 
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-06 12:47:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(9769):     at   
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions
(FragmentManager.java:1484)
```

Comment: Please publish a logcat trace.

Comment: Maybe it's sufficient to just post the stacktrace of the exception (*always* post the stacktrace of the exception). But the stanza trace could also be helpful.

Comment: there are non dude, it doesnt send any stanza but i post logcat